# Shrink Element Inside StackView

Tags: swift, constraints, uistackview

I have a stack view that expands from the left edge of my screen to the right. Inside it, I have a label and a button. The height of the StackView is 40, and the button has a set width of 40. I'm loading an image into the button, but I would like the button to be significantly smaller (ideally 10x10 & centered, inside the 40x40 button). Is there anyway to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add screenshot of view arrangement. Also 10x10 button may not work properly to receive touches!